# How can I select in prisma the elements with a condition on a 1-N relation?

Tags: prisma

I have the following prisma schema

```
model User {
  id         Int          @id      @default(autoincrement())
  userName   string       @unique
  complaints Complaint[]
}

model Complaint {
  id            Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  user          User               @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  creationTime  DateTime           @default(now())
  userId        Int
  priority      ComplaintPriority
}

enum ComplaintPriority {
  HIGH
  MEDIUM
  LOW
}
```

I need to select the users that have last complaint (as last I mean the complaint with latest `creationTime`) with priority value `HIGH`.

In other words:

1. if an user has 3 complaints and the last of these complaints has high priority the user should be part of the result (ignoring previous complaints)
2. If an user has 8 complaints (maybe some of those with high priority) and the last one has low priority the user should not be part of the results
3. If the user has no complaints at all the user should not be part of the results

I didn't find the prisma syntax for this operation. Does anybody has any idea how to do it?

Comment: Hey @raffaele quick clarification, do you want to sort `user` records based on the most recent `creationTime`  **OR** do you want to fetch `user` records and have the related `complaints` themselves sorted by `creationTime`.

Comment: Thanks for point out the ambiguity in my question, I didn't note it before, I'm going to update the question. Btw I'm interested to have the user records that fetch with `complaints` sorted by `creationTime` and last one of those complaints should have `priority` set to `HIGH`.

Comment: Oh okay, so you're saying it's the second of the two option that I mentioned (sort the `complaints` by `creationTime`, not the `users`)?  Also, you're saying _atleast_ one complaint should be set to `HIGH` but not necessarily _all_ of them?

Comment: Yes to first of your questions: i need to perform the search on the `user` considering the `complaint` related to the user with last `creationTime`. For your second question I'm interested to know just if the last of those `complaint` has high priority, I'm not interested at all to all the previous ones.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a bit, unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to create a query exactly as you have in mind (as of version 3.5.0 of Prisma).

Here's a workaround that you could perhaps consider:

1. Fetch all `user` records that have at least one complaint with `HIGH` priority. Include `complaint`  records and order them by `creationTime`.
2. Manually filter through the list in Node.js to keep appropriate `user` records.

```js
let users = await prisma.user.findMany({
    where: {
        complaints: {
            some: {
                priority: "HIGH"
            }
        }
    },

    include: {
        complaints: {
            orderBy: {
                creationTime: "desc"
            }
        }
    }
})

users = users.filter(user => user.complaints[0].priority == "HIGH")
```

It should be noted though, this isn't perfectly optimal if there are *really high* number of `user` records. In such a case, I would consider creating a raw SQL query using [`rawQuery`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access).